# Error al intentar subir archivo a directorio

Tags: php, fileupload

Estoy intentando subir un archivo a mi directorio ubicado en un servidor por medio de `inputfile` en HTML y lo manipulo desde el servidor con PHP donde le indico la ruta en la que deseo que quede guardado, pero no logro guardar el archivo cuando le doy en la acción de cargar archivo me sale el siguiente error:

> **Warning**:
> move_uploaded_file(//TestServer/Folder/File_00001.pdf): failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory in 
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\project\server.php** on line **96** 
>  
> **Warning**: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
> 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpBCE0.tmp' to '//TestServer/Folder/File_00001.pdf' in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\project\server.php**  on line

El código PHP que utilizo para la carga del documento es el siguiente:

```
$archivoPDF = $_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["name"];
        $rutaPDF = "//TestServer/Folder/";
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $rutaPDF . $archivoPDF)){
           echo "Archivo Cargado exitosamente";
        }else {
            echo "Error al cargar archivo";
        }
```

No sé si hay algo que me haga falta en la sentencia que acabo de compartir o saber que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: `No such file or directory` indica que estás intentando subir un archivo que no existe. Seguro que el proceso que corre el servidor con PHP tiene permisos para ver esa unidad de red?

Comment: @Alfabravo Si tengo permisos para ver la unidad de red, ya que adicional a este archivo estoy cargando otros dos los cuales contienen otro tipo de validaciones, lo curioso es que el tercer archivo que estoy agregando no me permite cargarlo correctamente, cada archivo va a rutas diferentes en el mismo servidor.

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$_FILES['pdfToUpload']['error']`